# I cant access variable from seperate file in my html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to populate a **dropdown** box but I keep getting an `undefined` error for all currencies when i reference them.

This code is given to me from a third party to accomplish the simple goal of populating a dropbox and editing a little text and i have no idea why the variable I need from the referenced `js` file is coming up `undefiened`

```js
var allCurrencies = {
  "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
  "BTC": "Bitcoin",
  "CAD": "Canadian Dollar",
  "EUR": "Euro",
  "JPY": "Japanese Yen",
  "RUB": "Russian Ruble",
  "USD": "United States Dollar"
};

// Initial data for exchange rates
var exchangeRates = {
  "disclaimer": "Usage subject to terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms",
  "license": "https://openexchangerates.org/license",
  "timestamp": 1534107604,
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "BTC": 0.000157753542,
    "CAD": 1.316853,
    "EUR": 0.879353,
    "JPY": 110.46550427,
    "USD": 1,
  }
};

/* Your solution goes here */
```

```html
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Currency Exchange</title>
   <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="currex.js" defer></script>
   <script>

   </script>
</head>
```

I am just looking for any starting point to help with this

Comment: No error messages are reported when I click "Run code snippet". Your [mcve] should *demonstrate the problem*! What variable? Where are you referencing it? Which of that code is *your* code and which is third party code? Where is this "dropbox" you mention?

Comment: Where is your dropdown code?

Comment: Maybe, if you write down the script that you are using to populate the drop down we could search some error or something. Now we only have something like a JSON object and a piece of HTML, but nothing like a javascript doing some stuf that we could analize.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> <script src="currex.js" defer></script>
> ```

You deferred the loading of the script, so it won't have run **before** the script element that immediately follows it.

Since it hasn't run yet, the variable isn't defined.

**Remove the `defer` attribute**.